# Book where the protagonists are transported from the past into a futuristic spaceship

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, spaceship, space

I am looking for a book I read on kindle a number of years ago (not an account I have access to now).

The concept was that 2 midshipmen (I think that was their rank) are transported forwards in time from a battle which took place in the Napoleonic wars on a Royal Navy warship to a Royal Navy spaceship.

Part of the story I recall being about their acclimatisation to the future and their training for the navy of this futuristic world.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could this be the *[Harry Heron](https://www.goodreads.com/series/290179-harry-heron)* series by Patrick G. Cox? The cover blurb for the second book in the series, *[Into the Unknown](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/30813174-into-the-unknown)*, reads:

> Harry Heron: Into the Unknown continues the exciting story begun in
> Harry Heron: Midshipman's Journey, the flagship book in the series. **A
> freak accident on board the HMS Spartan during a sea battle with the
> French navy in 1804 catapults Midshipman Harry Heron and his shipmates
> Ferghal O’Connor and Danny Gunn four hundred years into the future,
> landing them on the NECS Vanguard, flagship of the World Treaty
> Organisation Fleet.** While Captain Blackwood and Major Heron sort out
> the mystery and determine whether the young men are alive or dead,
> Harry and his friends are faced with the challenge of learning new
> roles aboard a spaceship. Just as they have found their footing, they
> are called upon to assist the Fleet in a rescue mission on the planet
> Pangaea, giving them the opportunity to prove that their unique skills
> from the past are still very relevant in the far distant future.